# i want to know the width of the <div> within my directives template ,and store in the variable how can i achieve that

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

### to know the width of div

i want to know the width of the  within the template ,and store in the variable how can i achieve that

```js
pp.directive('skillSlider',function()
  {
 return{
  template:'<div class="progress"></div>'
  } 
  });


----------
how to calculate the width of the div inside the directive template
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the link function to get access to the element using which you can get the width of the div.

```
pp.directive('skillSlider',function()
    {
       return{
              template:'<div class="progress"></div>',

              link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(element.width());
               })   
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `angular.element` e.g.:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).clientWidth;
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.class')[0]).clientWidth;
```

or if you have jQuery loaded

```
angular.element($('#id').width();
angular.element($('.class')[0]).width();
```